# Why isn't text showing in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I can't understand why the text isn't showing. I tried to reformat the program but it isn't showing the text.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
Test = "test"

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable = Test, width = 30)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, instead copy it into the question as a code block  (4 space indent at the start of the line)

Comment: `textvariable` is the wrong argument keyword. You need `text` here. `label = tk.Label(root, text=Test, width=30)`

Comment: Tnx for the help

Comment: @ktzr The OP has added the code as text to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) is the recommend documentation for the `tkinter`library.

The `Label.textvariable` attribute should point to a `tkinter.StringVar()` object:

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> test = StringVar()
>>> test.set('Hello')
>>> pinnarKvar = tk.Label(root, textvariable = test, width = 30)
>>> pinnarKvar.pack()
```

[image: Tk Label w/ textvariable]

HereI am using IDLE so I don't use `root.mainloop()` since it dynamically updates.

To change what you see, after you call `pinnarKvar.pack()` call `text.set()` to update.